# Ruby on Rails with Passenger and Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

I have an app running in production mode (I think), I've type on the terminal

> $ RAILS_ENV=production

but the app is still debugging the templates when by example I enter wrong url, I just want the server or the app show me an 404 page. What I need to do?

Comment: when you launch your server, you should use `RAILS_ENV=production rails server`

Comment: Are you testing locally (that is are the requests producing errors etc being made from the machine that is running nginx)?

Comment: Now I could do it properly but now I have another problem, I have an **/admin** interface but when I want to enter this url the server throws me "the web page is not available". Any help?